# How do I convert json file into HTML without adding them into an element first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

on jQuery's website there is a documentation says,

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

For those who have used this method know that it adds all the json attributes into the the variable called "iteams" and then it converts the "items" into html by adding the string into a new unordered list with a class called "my-new-list".

Now, say if I do not want to add a new unordered list with a class called "my-new-list", instead I want to convert the new variable into string and add into an existed HTML element, say with a class called "curtain," how do I go about the do that?

Here is my try:

```
var items = [];
var first = '<div class="panel"><div class="panel-gallery"><img src="',
    second = '" Alt=""></div></div>';
$.each( data, function( url ) {
    items.push( first + url + second );
    html: items.join( "" ).appendTo( ".curtain" );
});
```

Apparently that will give me an error on the line:

```
html: items.join( "" ).appendTo( ".curtain" );
```

Comment: What is the format of the data returned by your ajax request? I.e., what is in your `data` variable?

Comment: Oh, it's json I suppose. I tried "$('.panel-slider').append(first + val + second);" in the $.each function and it works in the dom tree but the images do not show up in html. I think that's because when loading the url via jquery the first part of the url (like localhost:8888 is not loaded).

Comment: have you tried putting `html: items.join( "" ).appendTo( ".curtain" );` outside loop ? It seems that on each loop iteration you are adding new divs to array and then adding all of them multiple times.

Comment: And then I tried adding localhost:8888 in first and have a complete url, it still won't load the images.

Comment: And yes, the html: XXX syntax was simply wrong to begin with. I don't think it can be used without adding a new element first.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker The `html:` syntax can be used if you are passing jQuery an object, as one of the parameters, with a property called `html`. In this case, it is incorrect syntax because you put it in the body of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, in a most simple way, it CANNOT be done.

Why?

Here is the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

In short, the .html() method in jQuery must have a "selector."

This means, you must have a selector to allow the objects to be convert into.

You have three ways to achieve your goal.

1) If you do not care to expand your variable "items", you can simple take it out from the code and use:

```
$('.yourClass').append(XXX);
```

It looks like your failed. This is because mounting string to DOM tree loop out the javascript engine on its first process, you can use load method but you might still fail. So you must use method 2 or 3.

2) Make use '.yourClass' is empty, and then:

```
$('.yourClass').html(XXX);
```

Now this is convenient but, you might not have an empty '.yourClass' so...

3) Creative a new class, lets call it '.newClass':

```
$( "<div/>", {
    "class": "newClass",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
```

And now take all the children of '.newClass' and append them to '.yourClass':

```
$(".newClass").children().appendTo(".yourClass");
```

Finally, remove '.newClass'.

```
$(".newClass").remove();
```

Difficult? Yes. That's how it has to be. Sorry pal.

Answer (score 3):

It gives you an error because it is not a valid syntax because you are putting it in a function, not a hash. If items.join returns html, just remove "html:" and do this:

```
$(items.join( "" )).appendTo( ".curtain" );
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, that doesn't convert the items (which is an array of objects) to string so it won't work (it will return undefined is not a function error).